# replace first array with second array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to the replace the first array with value of second array:

First array:

```
{link: [ 'hacking', 'license' ]}
```

Second array

```
{internalLink: [{orignal:'hacking', replace:'123456'}, {orignal:'license', replace:'654321'}]}
```

Into:

```
 {link: [ '123456', '654321' ]}
```

Hoe can I do this with underscore?

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: Please _explain_ the problem you are trying to solve. Don't just give us a cryptic input and output and ask us to make it work.

Comment: @Kev Fixx : atleast give a clear input and output.. I mean what should be the resulting array ?

Comment: @MithunGanatra Apparently that third code sample (which is not an array) is the desired resulting array.

Comment: The output is {link: [ '123456', '654321' ]}

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to replace the item in `link` Array with the `replace` property of the Object which has `original` property set to the item.

I suppose you're wanting something like, which uses `Array.filter` and `Array.map`

```
obj.link = obj.link.map(function(item){
   return anotherObj.internallink.filter(function(itm){
      return itm.original == item;
   })[0].replace;
});
```

Note that, I've used `original` as the property name as opposed to `orignal`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am just trying to figure is it possible to do it using underscore.